# Get the string between "[img]XXXXX[/img]" tags PHP

Tags: php

Hi i have a problem I don't now how get a string between the [img] [/img] tag

For example:

```
$string = "Hello i am new [img]nice_photo[/img] so here is my avatar [img]avatar[/img] ok its all";
```

I will get the string "avatar" and "nice_photo"

Please help thanks.

Edit:
Hmm I give a example what will make I have a string for example:
 `$s = "Hello [img] nice [img]https://imgur.com/ddd.jpg/[/img] this is a photo"`

And I have a array of permitted domains:

```
$domains = array("Imgur.com", "iv.com");
```

I will check the domain between the [img] [/img] If the domain between the tags is in the array $domains then is ok
 If the domain between the tags isn't in the array the string will be change to:

```
$s_new = "Hello [img] nice [img]***[/img] this is a photo"
```

Comment: If you **know for sure** that the `[img][/img]` tags will start with `[`, have `img`, and close with `]`, and have `/` if it's the closing tag,  you might be able to use regular expressions with [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and a capture group.

Comment: @Sop Nal - you can follow similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557894/php-preg-match-get-in-between-string

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_match`:

```
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/', $string, $matches);

// $matches[1] has all the matches
```

Comment: You're right! I changed it to a non-greedy wildcard instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I give a example what will make
I have a string for example: `$s = "Hello [img] nice [img]https://imgur.com/ddd.jpg/[/img] this is a photo"`

And I have a array of permitted domains:

```
$domains = array("Imgur.com", "iv.com");
```

I will check the domain between the [img] [/img] 
If the domain between the tags is in the array $domains then is og
If the domain between the tags isn't in the array the string will be change to:

```
$s_new = "Hello [img] nice [img]***[/img] this is a photo"
```